# How to log changes made to Permissions?

Tags: 2010, permissions

I need to keep a log for any changes made to user permissions. Is there a way to do it in SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the audit logging keeps track of it.

http://blogs.interfacett.com/configuring-auditing-sharepoint-2010

Old link, now broken:
http://davecoleman146.com/2011/02/14/setting-up-audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: I am wondering why did I asked such a question! It was already there. Thanks!

Comment: This link is also good - http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/auditing-permission-changes/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: link was broken and need to google again this phrase : setting up audit logging in-sharepoint 2010