# When modifying a List Item's permissions only does the last modified timestamp get updated?

Tags: permissions, timestamp

According to this https://superuser.com/questions/718784/does-changing-a-files-attribute-also-change-its-time-stamps if a Windows file has its permissions changed the `lastModified` timestamp is updated. Note we did not change the file, just the permissions.

Will Sharepoint do this same thing? Will Sharepoint update a file's `TimeLastModified` get updated on SharePoint documents when someone changes only file permissions?

Answer (score 0):

No. Changing permissions for a file does not change its metadata, including its timestamp. Only editing the file or its metadata will triger an update of the *Modified* and *ModifiedBy* fields.

Comment: is there any timestamp for such a thing?

Comment: Not that easily. However, by activating the SharePoint audit logs, it may be possible, see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/16708/35604.